# Flatten nested try/except clauses

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to try a number of different approaches at the same task, catching exceptions each time an approach fails. I know the exception which will be raised if an attempt fails (and it can be different for each attempt). After the last attempt, I want to give up gracefully and move on.

I currently do this through nested `try`/`except` clauses:

```
try:
    first_approach()
except Exception1:
    try:
        second_approach()
    except Exception2:
        try:
            third_approach()
        except:
            give_up()
except Exception2:
    try:
        third_approach()
    except:
        give_up()
```

But this looks bad to me because `third_approach()` is repeated. I can't see any help for this in [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html).
So how can I flatten this ugly nested code?

#### A concrete example

For example, imagine I am attempting to read a list of CSV files, without knowing their encoding in advance.

Some of the CSV files may even be XLS files posing as CSVs via their file extension.

I therefore want to try a few different encodings then, if none of those encodings work, try to read the file as excel.

```
for f in files:
    try:
        read_csv(f, encoding='utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        try:
            read_csv(f, encoding='latin1')
        except NotCsvError:
            try:
                read_excel(f)
            except:
                give_up()
    except NotCsvError:
        try:
            read_excel(f)
        except:
            give_up()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could loop over your approach-functions with a `for`/`else` loop.

The `else` clause runs only if the `for` is not terminated by the `break` statement.

```
approaches = ((first_approach, [arg1, arg2, ...], {'kwarg1':kwarg1, 'kwarg2':kwarg2, ...}, (Approach1Exception1, Approach1Exception2, ...)),
              (second_approach, ..., ..., ...),
              (third_approach, ..., ..., ...), 
              ...)

for approach, args, kwargs, exceptions in approaches:
    try:
        approach(*args, **kwargs)
        break
    except exceptions: 
        pass
else:
    give_up()
```

Comment: else without if?

Comment: @Rahul yes. The `else` block will execute if the `for` loop was not terminated by the `break` statement.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.

Comment: You could also put the "allowed exceptions" as a tuple in your `approaches` and then for each approach, `except allowed_exceptions` so you're not catching all possible exceptions across all approaches...

Comment: @JonClements that's clever!

Comment: @timgeb it *has* to be a `tuple` though... :)

Comment: @JonClements You could use any iterable `foo` and write `except tuple(foo)`.

Comment: @chepner indeed... I was just saying what `except` sees needs to be a `tuple`... wasn't saying where it should be made a tuple :) - although since it's a predefined set of arguments - it makes sense to have it as a tuple to start with in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Still nested, but DRYer:

```
for f in files:
    try:
        try:
            read_csv(f, encoding='utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            read_csv(f, encoding='latin1')
    except NotCsvError:
        try:
            read_excel(f)
        except:
            give_up()
```

In the outer block, you try using UTF-8 first, then Latin-1 if it fails with a UnicodeDecodeError. If *either* of those fails with a NotCsvError, control passes to the outer `except` clause. This takes advantage of the fact that `read_excel` doesn't care which encoding(s) you previously tried.

Answer (score 0):

Though three levels of nestedness are still present in my solution, the logic of trying different approaches is flattened out:

```
ex = None
while True:
    try:
        if ex is None:
            first_approach()
        elif ex is Exception1:
            second_approach()
        elif ex is Exception2:
            third_approach()
        else:
            give_up()
        break
    except:
        ex = sys.exc_info()[0]
```

Note, however, that this code is not 100% equivalent to your version. For example, it will end up as an infinite loop if `third_approach()` raises `Exception2`.